# Java. Убрать неймспейсы при маршаллинге

Tags: java, xml, namespace

Использую javax.xml.bind.Marshaller

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

var marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new ExchangeJaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperImpl());
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, document);

var doc = new XmlDocument(document.getDocumentElement());
```

После этого получаю сериализацией с помощью LSSerializer xml:

```
var byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
var registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
var impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
var writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
var output = impl.createLSOutput();
output.setByteStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
writer.write(element, output);
return byteArrayOutputStrm.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Получается xml c неймспейсами вида:

```
xmlns:ns210="urn:ru:nap:1.0"
xmlns:ns2339="urn:ru:typeCu:1.0"
xmlns:ns2353="urn:ru:cust:1.0"> 
<ns210:name>Игорь</ns210:name>
<ns210:secondName>Преображенский</ns210:secondName>
```

А хочу получить xml с неймспейсами вида:

```
<name xmlns="urn:ru:nap:1.0">Игорь</name>
<secondName xmlns="urn:ru:nap:1.0">Преображенский</secondName>
```

Т.е. указывать неймспейс каждый раз полностью. Как правильно реализовать?